# Parallels creates /Users/Shared/Parallels on boot, blocks ZFS /Users from mounting

Tags: parallels-desktop, zfs

Does anyone know why Parallels creates /Users/Shared/parallels on boot? Or what creates it?

I have a ZFS volumes for /Users. However, since installing Parallels 7 I've found that the ZFS volume can't mount because earlier in the boot process Parallels have already put an empty Shared/Parallels/backups directory into /Users.

Any way to disable this, or delay it til after ZFS mounts would be great.

At the moment I have to log into a console, use a spare admin user to remove /Users, then zfs mount my /Users. All very irritating.

There are several system LaunchAgents for Parallels, but not very descriptive.

- OS: 10.8.2
- Parallels: updated Parallels 7.
- ZFS: ZFS Community Edition

Updates for Graham:

```
alex@smiley:~|⇒  ls -lrt /Library/LaunchAgents/*ara* 
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  797 Sep  3 16:12 /Library/LaunchAgents/com.parallels.vm.prl_pcproxy.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  565 Sep  3 16:13 /Library/LaunchAgents/com.parallels.desktop.launch.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  721 Sep  3 16:13 /Library/LaunchAgents/com.parallels.DesktopControlAgent.plist
alex@smiley:~|⇒  sudo launchctl list | grep arallel  
228 -   com.parallels.vm.prl_naptd
78  -   com.parallels.desktop.launchdaemon
alex@smiley:~|⇒  kextstat | grep arallel
  111    0 0xffffff7f8241f000 0x7000     0x7000     com.parallels.kext.prl_usb_connect (7.0 15107.796624) <39 7 5 4 3 1>
  112    1 0xffffff7f82426000 0x5c000    0x5c000    com.parallels.kext.prl_hypervisor (7.0 15107.796624) <10 9 7 5 4 3 1>
  113    0 0xffffff7f82482000 0x4000     0x4000     com.parallels.kext.prl_hid_hook (7.0 15107.796624) <7 5 4 3 1>
  114    0 0xffffff7f82486000 0xc000     0xc000     com.parallels.kext.prl_netbridge (7.0 15107.796624) <112 5 4 3 1>
  115    0 0xffffff7f82492000 0x4000     0x4000     com.parallels.kext.prl_vnic (7.0 15107.796624) <35 5 4 3 1>
```

Looks like DesktopControlAgent isn't loaded.

---

Following Graham's pointer to wait4path I updated  com.parallels.desktop.launchdaemon.plist in /Library/LaunchDaemons to:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/bin/bash</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>wait4path /Users/Shared/Parallels &amp;&amp; /Library/Parallels/Parallels\ Service.app/Contents/Resources/ParallelsDispatcherService start</string>
</array>
```

That seems to have fixed it. At least, Parallels still runs, and the computer loads properly at start-up.

List output is this:

```
alex@smiley:~|⇒  sudo launchctl list com.parallels.desktop.launchdaemon
Password:
{
    "Label" = "com.parallels.desktop.launchdaemon";
    "LimitLoadToSessionType" = "System";
    "OnDemand" = true;
    "LastExitStatus" = 0;
    "PID" = 88;
    "TimeOut" = 30;
    "ProgramArguments" = (
        "/bin/bash";
        "-c";
        "wait4path /Users/Shared/Parallels && /Library/Parallels/Parallels\ Service.app/Contents/Resources/ParallelsDispatcherService start";
    );
```

Not sure if there's a cleaner way of doing the plist.

Comment: Please add to your question the outputs from `sudo launchctl list | grep arallel` and `kextstat | grep arallel` (assuming *arallel* will find all Parallels-related files) – thanks. Cross-post [Parallels prevents /Users](http://zevo.getgreenbytes.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1525)

Comment: Which folder have to defined to be the default directory for virtual machines (it's `/Users/Shared/Parallels` here)?

Comment: /iLife/VMs/Parallels/ is my default location.

Comment: Does booting in verbose mode give a sense of the point at which the path is created?

Comment: No, no messages about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two commands to discover more about the two loaded items:

```
sudo launchctl list com.parallels.vm.prl_naptd

sudo launchctl list com.parallels.desktop.launchdaemon
```

I can't guess the meaning of prl_naptd but http://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22com.parallels.vm.prl_naptd%22+%22addPaths%22 suggests some relationship between `com.parallels.vm.prl_naptd` and *addPaths* so maybe focus attention on this launch agent.

An early guess: a workaround might involve `wait4path`

[wait4path(1) OS X Manual Page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/wait4path.1.html)

Comment: I've tried adding in a wait4path into the ProgramArguements line before the command, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: For the modified agent, please add to your question the output from `sudo launchctl list com.parallels.vm.prl_naptd`